# Why removed List<Entity> not reflectiong when SubmitChanges() called?

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have this e.g. code:

```
    var list = (from item in db.Table
        select item).ToList();
```

[do processing where I modify,add,remove items to the list with a DX GridControl]
[Ensure inserted items]
[I can see that item(s) are not in the list]

db.SubmitChanges();

Changes not reflecting the DataBase for removed items.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the list in order to update the database. You have to modify the database entity collections. For example: `db.Table.Remove(instance)`

Edit: I believe the above syntax is EF4 only. For the original EF, you need to use `DeleteOnSubmit`, which is a method on your entity container.

Comment: I guess anthares is telling the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you apply your changes with     `db.SubmitChanges();` method on your data Context?
Example from msdn:

```
var deleteOrderDetails =
    from details in db.OrderDetails
    where details.OrderID == 11000
    select details;

foreach (var detail in deleteOrderDetails)
{
    db.OrderDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(detail);
}

try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Provide for exceptions.
}
```

Here is the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx

I'm not sure that you can populate the changes from your List to the database if this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So i should keep a list with deleted Id's and DeleteInSubmit(Id). This makes sense...i'll try.

Comment: No you should provide Entity objects to DeleteOnSubmit to put them into a pending delete state